# How can I create a matrix from a list?

Tags: python, matrix

I am given a list which somehow represents a matrix, but it is in the list format, like

```
["OOX","XOX","XOX"]
```

Is there any way i can convert it into a matrix?
I have gone through numpy, but could not figure out!

Comment: Do you want a matrix or a list of lists?

Comment: I would guess that you want this: `np.matrix([list(s) for s in ["OOX","XOX","XOX"]])`, if not, can you provide your expected output?

Comment: In what sense is that not already a matrix? If you name it `matrix`, then you can already access its elements like `matrix[i][j]`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

numpy is overkill for this. For something like Tic-tac-toe, a list of lists is enough.

If `'OOX'` is a string, then `list('OOX')` is the list `['O','O','O']`.

You can combine `list` with a list comprehension:

Something like:

```
>>> rows =  ["OOX","XOX","XOX"]
>>> board = [list(row) for row in rows]
>>> board
[['O', 'O', 'X'], ['X', 'O', 'X'], ['X', 'O', 'X']]
```

Used like:

```
>>> board[0][2]
'X' (3rd entry in first row).
```

Note that lists are mutable, so the elements can be changed as well as read:

`board[0][2] = 'O'` will change the `'X'` in that position to an `'O'`.

Comment: Your usage example is rather pointless. No need to do the conversion at all if you're just reading. Could just do `rows[0][2]` instead. I'd add an example where you **write** an entry.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Good point. I was mostly illustrating the way the indexing worked, regarding it as somewhat obvious that you could write as well as read. Still, it couldn't hurt to show that the elements can be changed, so I will do so.

Comment: Yeah, it's just a strange question. If the he had asked for writing capability, I'm sure you would've shown that right away. But he didn't, and I'm not even sure that's what he wants. Might actually just be asking for a two-dimensional **display**...

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this:

```
In [4]: a = ["OOX","XOX","XOX"]

In [5]: m = np.array([*map(list, a)])

In [6]: m
Out[6]: 
array([['O', 'O', 'X'],
       ['X', 'O', 'X'],
       ['X', 'O', 'X']], 
      dtype='<U1')
```